# Could Emacs convert C++ braces to hanging while re-indenting buffer?

Tags: c++, emacs, elisp, indentation

When I re-indent a C++ buffer, I'd like to convert code like this:

```
void foo(int a)
{
    try
    {
        for (unsigned int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        {
            if (++a)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    } catch (...)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

to code like this:

```
void foo(int a) {
    try {
        for (unsigned int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
            if (++a) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (...) {
    ;
}
```

Also, I want the class definitions and namespaces to be untouched.
Does this functionality exist in Emacs?

I realize that this can done with a bunch of regexps,
but it'd be nicer to use a ready-made function that handles
all the edge cases and all.

Comment: You could try `indent -br`. http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/indent.html#SEC9

Comment: Thanks, that does look useful. I guess I could hook it up via command on region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem mostly solved with astyle:

```
(defun cpp-astyle()
  (interactive)
  (let (beg end)
    (if (region-active-p)
        (setq beg (region-beginning)
              end (region-end))
      (setq beg (point-min)
            end (point-max)))
    (shell-command-on-region beg end "astyle -A3 -U -p -k3" nil t)))
```

Out of 12 styles that it supports none match exactly what I want,
but this one is pretty close (only function implementation opening brace is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

A simple macro could do the job, like:

```
(setq last-kbd-macro
   "\C-s{\336\C-e")
```

Followed by: <kbd>M-0</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>.

Comment: Doesn't handle the classes and namespaces.
Also, no undo.

Answer (score 0):

Note: See my edit, below.

You can do this with replace-regexp in two different ways.

1.) To do this with elisp, go to the beginning of the buffer and type M-: (which lets you give an s-expression to evaluate). Then type

```
(replace-regexp "\n.*{" " {")
```

and press return.

2.) To do this interactively, either run M-x replace-regexp or type M-% (which does the same thing). When asked to what replace, type `C-q C-j` followed by `.*{`

When asked what to replace it with, type `" {"` (without the quotes -- I had to put them there to show the space before the curly brace).

Then press return to run the function.

The reason you have to type `C-q C-j` for the newline is because the interactive replace-regexp doesn't let you use `\n`.

Also, as a side note, if you're trying to find or figure out a regular expression, use `re-builder`. It is extremely helpful.

**Edit:**

As pointed out in the comments, if the code does not match the given input example style, it is possible for my regexp to delete code. Here's a different version that helps to avoid that. It still isn't perfect, but no regexp should ever be used blindly.

```
(replace-regexp "\n\s *{" " {")
```

This will make sure to only match and delete whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this is a really weak regexp.
It actually deletes code. I don't feed my precious code to
a regexp unless it's been tested for at least 5 years:).

Comment: Interesting. It worked perfectly in emacs for me with your exact code sample. I made sure to try both methods twice, just to be certain it worked. I'm not sure how this deleted any code.

Comment: Here's what I suggest. Open your code in a buffer, then run M-x rebuilder. Give it the "\n.*{" and see what matches. I'd be curious to know the results.

Comment: I'm guessing that my regexp-fu is stronger than yours:).
The example is trivial - `(replace-regexp "\n.*{" " {")` will wipe `\nfoo{`.

Comment: That's true, but that's not applicable to the code sample you gave. Assuming you stick to the same coding convention throughout (which is a good idea), and that coding convention matches your first code sample, every opening brace should be on its own line. If you have code getting deleted with my regexp, like your \nfoo{ example, then your code isn't formatted properly to begin with. 

So, yes, my regexp can delete code and shouldn't be used on every file ever, but given your expected input and output samples, it works. :-)

Comment: That's kind of the whole point of asking the question. To do the job safely.
It cannot be done with regexps, unless they're extremely thoroughly debugged.

Comment: I edited my answer to have a second, "safer" option. Still might not be perfect, but these regexps are how I would solve this issue for myself, modifying this as necessary, of course. re-buidler FTW.